# Select 5 random results in 10 with order_by & limit CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table with 500 results.

I need to order by Players with DESC option, then limit for 10 results and select 5 results aleatory of the 10 with CodeIgniter.

What I have:

```
public function getServers(){
    $this->db2->from('server');
    $this->db2->order_by("players", "desc");
    $this->db2->limit(5);

    $query  = $this->db2->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to select the 10 top results in your database, ordered by column players in descending order, and then select 5 of these in random?

Just change one line of your code to:

```
 $this->db2->limit(10);
```

And then call the method like:

```
$my_random_five = array_rand($this->getServers(), 5);
```

Then also consider using http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look something like this as suggested by mark above

```
            $my_random_five = array_rand($this->getServers(), 5);
            public function getServers(){
                $this->db2->from('server');
                $this->db2->order_by("players", "desc");
                $this->db2->limit(10);
                $query  = $this->db2->get();
                if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                        $data[] = $row;
                    }
                    return $data;
                }
                return false;
            }
```